# How to save data factory SQL query with paramters to the SQL DB, and then call it from a pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the following sql query with pipeline parameters

```
SELECT * FROM @{pipeline().parameters.Table} WHERE 
@{pipeline().parameters.KeyColumn} > 
@{activity('LookupExistingKey').output.firstRow.KeyValue} AND 
@{pipeline().parameters.KeyColumn} <= 
@{activity('LoopupNewKey').output.firstRow.NewKeyValue}
```

The query is stored within a database and in my pipeline I write @pipeline.parameters.SelectSatement. At execution time the pipeline should fetch the querystring from the DB and execute it.

Error

```
Operation on target Copy data failed: Failure happened on 'Source' side. 
'Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Must declare the scalar 
variable "@pipeline".,Source=.Net SqlClient Data 
Provider,SqlErrorNumber=137,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=2,Errors=
[{Class=15,Number=137,State=2,Message=Must declare the scalar variable 
"@pipeline".,},],'
```

I would like to save the query (with parameters) to a DB and then call it dynamically from within my Pipeline. But it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide the snippet of your pipeline and how you are calling the select statement?

Answer (score 0):

When adding string value with variable or a parameter, use `concat()` function in the expression to concatenate both.

```
@concat('select * from ',pipeline().parameters.tablename, ' where ', pipeline().parameters.KeyColumn, ' = ', pipeline().parameters.KeyValue)
```

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply. What are the commas doing?

Comment: Hi, here comma is to separate string with the parameter value. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#concat) for usage details.

Comment: But why does it not work with string interpolation?